# Exporting Speed Dial settings from within Firefox into Chrome Speed dial

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons, speed-dial

Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit

I usually use Firefox as my browser of choice and have been using the Addin Speed Dial for ages.  I have many sites added on multiple tabs within it.

I have just installed the Google Chrome browser which also has the Speed Dial Extension.  Is there a way to export/import/copy/sync my Speed Dial settings I have in Firefox to the Speed Dial extension in Chrome?

I know I can export from Speed Dial in Firefox but can't see any easy way to import from Speed Dial in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [Speed Dial for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4810/) and [Speed Dial for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dgpdioedihjhncjafcpgbbjdpbbkikmi) are made by two different developers. The Firefox version allows you to import\export data but the Chrome version has no such options.

In Firefox Tools >> Add-ons >> Speed Dial Options >> Actions there are options to import, export, restore from backup, etc.

In Chrome going to Extension >> Speed Dial Options it only allows you to make cosmetic changes to the start page (spacing, theme, etc).

So currently it doesn't look possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - i was kind of thinking the same thing