# Chrome Extension - Speed Dial - Export/Import Settings

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I heavily use Speed Dial Chrome extension. I have configured it with url shortcuts and custom icons on my Windows 7 Ultimate desktop.

**How can I copy these settings from my desktop to my Windows 7 Ultimate laptop?**

- Both Chrome browsers sync with the same account.
- I tried copying all data from my desktop's
  `C:\Users\neo\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\dgpdioedihjhncjafcpgbbjdpbbkikmi\2.1_0`
  to the corresponding laptop folder, but still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! I did it. It's possible.

Copy the following file from your source chrome installation to the corresponding destination installation and overwrite.

```
C:\Users\<<user name>>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\chrome-extension_dgpdioedihjhncjafcpgbbjdpbbkikmi_0.localstorage
```

It is nothing but the local SQLite database file Speed Dial uses to store dial information.
If more interested, you can use [Mike's T SQLite Database App](http://saxmike.com/MySoftware/MySoftware.asp?Menu=MYSOFTWARE) to open this file and dig into the key values pairs of various dial parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the last line of the answer here,

[Exporting Speed Dial settings from within Firefox into Chrome Speed dial](https://superuser.com/questions/147899/exporting-speed-dial-settings-from-within-firefox-into-chrome-speed-dial)

it says

*In Chrome going to Extension >> Speed Dial Options it only allows you to make cosmetic changes to the start page (spacing, theme, etc).*

So currently it doesn't look possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just successfully accomplished this. The file is a database:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases\chrome-extension_jpfpebmajhhopeonhlcgidhclcccjcik_0
```

File Name: 4

Just overwrite the old file onto the new installation and it should work immediately. The import settings function in Speed Dial 2 failed to work properly and this was a successful workaround.